# Split a single sql file into multiple files

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have a file master.sql containing many create table ddl's.

master.sql

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id numeric(38) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    email_address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    full_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE inventory (
    inventory_id numeric(38) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    store_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    product_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    product_inventory numeric(38) NOT NULL
) ;
```

I want to split this file into separate files-one each for a table. For that i'm using [rubin's](https://www.unix.com/member_modal.php?u=302033432) solution [here](https://www.unix.com/302235656-post4.html).

Here is the awk command i used.

```
awk '/CREATE TABLE/{f=0 ;n++; print >(file=n); close(n-1)} f{ print > file}; /CREATE TABLE/{f=1}'  master.sql
```

While Executing awk command generate files with table count without any extension. tried to contact using this [article](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html)

When creating each sql file i want to change file name name for table name.

Eg.

- customers.sql
- inventory.sql

I'm trying use awk command for get table name form master.sql. Is that possible to getting table name while iteration master.sql.

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple 2 step process:

```
# Split the files when the string CREATE TABLE is found
csplit master.sql '/CREATE TABLE/'

# Read the first line, extract table name and rename the file
for f in $(ls xx*); 
do 
    table_name=`head -1 $f | awk '{ sub(/.*CREATE TABLE /, ""); sub(/ .*/, ""); print }'`
    mv $f "$table_name.sql"
    echo "Renaming $f to $table_name.sql"; 
done;
```

->

```
Renaming xx00 to customers.sql
Renaming xx01 to inventory.sql
```

->

```
$ ls
customers.sql inventory.sql master.sql

$ cat customers.sql
  CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id numeric(38) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    email_address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    full_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ;

$ cat inventory.sql
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    inventory_id numeric(38) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    store_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    product_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    product_inventory numeric(38) NOT NULL
) ;
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"} /CREATE TABLE/{fn = $3 ".sql"; print $0 ";" > fn; close(fn);}' master.sql
```

the `BEGIN` block will split the input into sql statements (rather than lines) by using the `;` character as a record separator.

then you can print the statement contents if the line matches `CREATE TABLE` to a file name based on the the third field (the table name)

Note: this may not work so well if there are any sql comments containing `;`

EDITED to close files (see comment by @ed-morton )

Answer (score 1):

That awk command you used is ridiculously complicated for what you're doing. All it needed to be was:

```
awk '/CREATE TABLE/{close(n); n++} {print > n}' file
```

and for your new requirements it's just a tweak to:

```
$ awk '/CREATE TABLE/{close(out); out=$3 ".sql"} {print > out}' file
```

```
$ head *.sql
==> customers.sql <==
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id numeric(38) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    email_address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    full_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ;


==> inventory.sql <==
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    inventory_id numeric(38) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    store_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    product_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    product_inventory numeric(38) NOT NULL
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified script
Called: >./Split_db.sh ./master.sql

## extended limit for more than 99 files creaded by script

```
#!/bin/sh

# Split the files when the string CREATE TABLE is found
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
##### OPTIONS VERIFICATION #####

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Need parametr. Example ( ./Split_db.sh ./master.sql )"
 exit 1
fi

csplit -n 4 -k $1 '/^CREATE TABLE .*/' '{800}'

# Read the first line, extract table name and rename the file
for f in $(ls xx*);
do
table_name=`head -1 $f | awk '{ sub(/.*CREATE TABLE /, ""); sub(/ .*/, ""); print }'`
mv $f "$table_name.sql"
echo "Renaming $f to $table_name.sql";
done;
```